# Continuous emits in flask-socketio (websockets). Is this the right approach?

Tags: python, flask, websocket, flask-socketio

### Background information

---

I'm working on a flask website where real-time data is needed from the server. For this i have implemented a solution with `flask-socketio`:

```py
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()
from .. import socketio # SocketIO object defined in parent
from flask import session, request

@socketio.on('get_info_test')
@login_required_ws
def get_info():
    result = {"result": None, "data": None}
    try:
        result["data"] = get_test_data(session.get("user_id")) # get data for user
        result["result"] = "success"
    except:
        result["result"] = "Unknown error while getting data"
    finally:
        return result
```

This only works once, but i need continuous data. For this I've come up with an idea to use a decorator that wraps this function and applies a loop to it.

```py
runningUserSids = set()
def emitLoop(emitString: str, frequency=0.5):
    def checkForExitStatus(function):
        @functools.wraps(function)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            sid = request.sid
            # already running for this user, don't run again
            if sid in runningUserSids:
                return
            print("Running new thread")
            #add to sid list
            runningUserSids.add(sid)
            # make sure data is recieved using a simple callback
            got = False
            def callbackGot():
                nonlocal got
                got = True
            # sid will be removed from the set when user disconnects
            while sid in runningUserSids:
                got = False
                output = function(*args, **kwargs)
                socketio.emit(emitString, output, callback=callbackGot)
                eventlet.sleep(frequency)
                try:
                    # timeout incase user disconnects
                    # sid is removed from set and loop is exited
                    with eventlet.Timeout(5):
                        while not got:
                            eventlet.sleep(frequency)
                except eventlet.timeout.Timeout:
                    print("timed out")
            print("Stopped running thread")
            return
        return wrapper
    return checkForExitStatus

# stop emitting when user disconnects
@socketio.on("disconnect")
def disconnected_stop_jobs():
    runningUserSids.discard(request.sid)
```

Applying this decorator to the function yields:

```py
@socketio.on('get_info_test')
@emitLoop('info_test')
@login_required_ws
def get_info():
    result = {"result": None, "data": None}
    try:
        result["data"] = get_test_data(session.get("user_id")) # get data for user
        result["result"] = "success"
    except:
        result["result"] = "Unknown error while getting data"
    finally:
        return result
```

Which continuously `emit`s data to the user every 0.5 seconds.

### The problem

---

This approach feels very hacky and poorly designed. It also causes the flask server to slow down and stop responding after a while. I'd like to know how to **improve on this method in case it's a good direction to take**, and if not **show me a good example of how i would correctly send `emit`s like this while also ensuring the client is receiving the data**.

Thanks

Comment: What does the `get_test_data()` function do? Do you have the standard library monkey-patched for eventlet compatibility?

Comment: @Miguel It fetches required data from mysql and redis servers. The file containing all handlers for socketio is monkey patched.

Comment: [This project](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/examples/tutorial/flaskr/db.py) uses the same method for getting databases. Mine just has an extra line for redis.

Comment: Monkey patching needs to be applied globally, you can't apply it on a single file. It should be done as early as possible, ideally in the main file, above all other imports. Maybe the server is sluggish due to bad monkey patching.